# generic function with parameter of type T and K, where K is keyof T and an array?

Tags: function, typescript, generics

In typescript it's possbile to declare a function that expects a type and one of its keys as parameters:

```
function foo<T, K extends keyof T>(object: T, key: K)
```

In the function body you're then able to get or set the value of the `object`'s  key value and even extract the type of the key (`T[k]`):

```
function setter<T, K extends keyof T>(object: T, key: K){
  return (value: T[K]) => {
    obj[key] = value;
  };      
}

function logger<T, K extends keyof T>(object: T, key: K){
  console.log(obj[key]);   
}
```

**Question:**

Is it possbile to have generic type `K` that `extends keyof T` and is an array?
(In other words: `K` must be an array and a key of type `T`)

**Example use case:**

```
function lengthLogger<T, K /*extends keyof T and is array*/>(object: T, key: K){
  console.log(object[key].length)     
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. The best one is to declare `T` as being a record of `K` of `any[]`

```
function lengthLogger<T extends Record<K, any[]>, K extends keyof T>(object: T, key: K) {
    console.log(object[key].length)
}

lengthLogger({
    foo: "",
    bar: ["", ""]
}, 'bar')

lengthLogger({
    foo: "",
    bar: ["", ""]
}, 'foo') // Error
```

This gives both call site and declaration type safety.

Another option you will find is to use conditional types to extract in `K` only the properties of a specific type. This works well for the call site but you will need type assertions for the declaration:

```
type ExtractKeysOfType<T, TValue> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends TValue ? P : TValue}[keyof T]
function lengthLogger<T , K extends ExtractKeysOfType<T, any[]>>(object: T, key: K) {
    console.log((object as any)[key].length)
}

lengthLogger({
    foo: "",
    bar: ["", ""]
}, 'bar')

lengthLogger({
    foo: "",
    bar: ["", ""]
}, 'foo') // Error
```

Comment: @Truntle it's the better one in most cases