# Unable to infer property type even though it's extending from a record definition

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I'm confused why typescript is unable to infer that `destination[destinationProperty]` is a `TChild` when `TParent` extends `Record<TParentProperty, TChild>` which should allow it to infer that the property is of type `TChild`.

```
class Person  {
  favoriteDog: Dog | undefined;
}

class Dog  {
  name: string;
}

  function mapSingle<
    TChild extends object | undefined,
    TParent extends Record<TParentProperty, TParentPropertyType>,
    TParentProperty extends Extract<keyof TParent, string>,
    TParentPropertyType extends TChild,
  >(
    destination: TParent,
    destinationProperty: TParentProperty,
    source: TChild,
  ) {
    destination[destinationProperty] = source; // Error Line
  }
```

> Type 'TChild' is not assignable to type 'TParent[TParentProperty]'.
>
> Type 'object | undefined' is not assignable to type 'TParent[TParentProperty]'.
>
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'TParent[TParentProperty]'.(2322)

[Typescript Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCmAnCB7AdtaBvAUJgZmAG4qICWALvACIoDmAXNLXdAD7QCuaAJvPmTTweAbhwBfHDlCQYLTLkxowAW3hMIFcmjpjJeaPm7AKZdNBVgADgGVBdEPAA8BzABUAwgAsyIHtHgADypeGBQAIwAreBN2Ll5+QWEAGldoN1gwRHg0CgDgnJ4YACUY0h4nDKycilhEFCskCgBPZPTM7Ny6hqbmt2bGgD5UzHcOmu7GxBb8kKLoAFFgxDATJwBreGaUfHbq3LbNbTphtKrO2vqplv7G2cKYTx8-EehBgAo0vk1BMFN0JjnGqvTDfUzKf5oSa9QHjLpXXog6CoTiIYDqdLeXw8V4ASmwX3gPwhZjQAG0wb9IdDps0ALrQAC8yJQqPRYkwkiAA)

Comment: I'm not sure why you need this to be so complicated as something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMMDbm) works? What am I missing?

Comment: @catgirlkelly your version doesn't support passing *undefined* for the source property e.g. `mapSingle(new Person(), "favoriteDog", undefined)`

Comment: Wait I'm not sure what you mean... In [here](https://tsplay.dev/mq5nZm) I call it both with a dog and undefined but it seems to work fine?

Comment: @catgirlkelly well isn't that interesting.

Comment: So apparently the problem is exacerbated by [find in the more complex version of this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72077701/mapping-relating-objects-together-using-a-generic-mapper).

Comment: Could you link a playground with your linked question and an attempt to implement my suggestion?

Comment: @catgirlkelly want to post your first comment as an answer?  And Yes I can...

Comment: I'd only like to post an answer if I definitely know it's right and solves the problem. If it does solve your problem then I will.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244444/discussion-between-erik-philips-and-catgirlkelly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit complicating it too much here, something like this can work:

```
class Person  {
  favoriteDog: Dog | undefined;
}

class Dog  {
  name: string;
}

function mapSingle<
  Parent,
  ParentProp extends keyof Parent,
  Child extends Parent[ParentProp],
>(
  destination: Parent,
  destinationProperty: ParentProp,
  source: Child,
) {
  destination[destinationProperty] = source;
}

mapSingle(new Person(), "favoriteDog", new Dog())
mapSingle(new Person(), "favoriteDog", undefined)
```

This is the simplest version; you have one `Parent`, the property `ParentProp`, and the type of that property `Child`. No need for the extra generic parameters!

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mMMDbm)